# Delete a row only into the join table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

**Question**

Is it possible to delete a row into a join table created by @ManyToMany annotation?

**Context**

With this schema :

- TAG
- TAGS_ARTICLES
- ARTICLE

When a tag is removed from `public Set<Tag> tags` (a list into `ARTICLE` class) corresponding rows into `TAGS_ARTICLES` is removed too, but not the tag into `TAG` table.

The only way is to create a SQL script or JPA/Hibernate allow us to do that with annotations?

**Code**

My current code is : `article.getTags().remove(tag);`

This line remove the tag from the list, but the change is not done in database.

**Conclusion**

I saw this post : [How to delete a row in join table with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235303/how-to-delete-a-row-in-join-table-with-jpa) , but relative tag must be deleted too (not my case).

Thanks.

**Edit 1 : Expected result in database**

*Before delete*

```
ARTICLE

| article_id |
| a1         |
| a2         |
| a3         |

TAGS_ARTICLES

| article_id | tag_id |
| a1         | t1     |
| a1         | t2     |
| a2         | t2     |

TAG

| article_id |
| t1         |
| t2         |
```

*After delete t1 from a1 tag list*

```
ARTICLE

| article_id |
| a1         |
| a2         |
| a3         |

TAGS_ARTICLES

| article_id | tag_id |
| a2         | t1     |
| a2         | t2     |

TAG

| article_id |
| t1         |
| t2         |
```

**Edit 2 : Join table code**

```
@Entity
public class Article {
     ...
     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name = "tags_articles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idarticle"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idtag")
     )
     private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
     ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking to be honest. I'm lost. You wrote "... but not the tag into TAG table". So which rows do you want to delete?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear... Only the row into the join table, so only the row into TAGS_ARTICLES. I don't want to remove the tag into TAG because it can be used by other articles.

Comment: @LppEdd I added an example in my question.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: see comments

Using this set-up should produce the wanted result

```
class Article {
   ...  

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(...)
   private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}

class Tag {
   ...

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
   private Set<Article> articles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The `Article` entity is taking ownership of the relationship.

---

*Old answer*.

> When a tag is removed from `public Set<Tag> tags` (a list into ARTICLE
>   class) the corresponding row into TAGS_ARTICLES is removed too, but
>   not the tag into TAG table.

By this I understand that the *orphaned* records are not deleted. And you want to delete them. Is this correct?

You might want to try using the Hibernate specific `@Cascade` annotation ([documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html)).
Just annotate your `Collection<T>` field.

```
@ManyToMany(...)
@Cascade(CascadeType.REMOVE) // or CascadeType.DELETE
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
```

Be sure to include it from the `org.hibernate.annotations` package.

Comment: When I remove the tag from the article, the tag is still correctly removed from the list but if I do a GET request (to test, I use Postman) on the article, the tag is still present on the list `tags`. So, no change even if I add `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")`.

Comment: @N.Lamblin do you persist the entity via Entity Manager? Are you under a Transaction?

Comment: If I'm under a Transaction, it is not my choice. About Entity Manager, I use the package `import javax.persistence.*;`. I'm a beginner with these tools (sorry for my incompetency), so it's hard to tell you, but I didn't explicitly create an EntityManager instance.

Comment: @N.Lamblin if I understood correctly you are using Spring Repositories, right?

Comment: @N.Lamblin than after removing the element from the set, you should call the save() method of your entity Repository

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working. So, with Spring I have to use save() everytime? It is not possible to do it "automatically"? Then, I have misunderstood something ...

Comment: @N.Lamblin with Spring you need to call save() explicitly when **not** under a transaction. If you're under a transaction (see the Transactional annotation for example) Spring will persist the entity when the transaction is committed. I suggest you to read from the official Spring documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/index.html
I learned everything from there

Comment: So I'm going to rereread this documentation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of entity operation is depends on ownership of the relation, which is determined by where you place the **mappedBy** attribute to the annotation. Entity having `mappedBy` is the one which is not the owner. Both side of relationship cannot be owner.

Here you need to decide the correct owner. Let say the Tag is the owner. Then when deleting a Tag the relation TAGS_ARTICLES  will be updated automatically. when deleting a TAGS_ARTICLES you have to take care of deleting the relation yourself.

```
@Entity
public class Tag{
    @ManyToMany
    Set<Tag_Articles> articles;
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Tag_Articles{
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="articles")
    Set<Tag> tags;
    //...
}
```

For the entity relationship like above, you can try something like this -

```
entityManager.remove(articles)
for (Tag tag: articles.tags) {
     tag.articiles.remove(articles);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with this answer, I have to create an entity `Tags_Articles`, is it an obligation to solve my problem? Because my wish is an automatic update.