# Query to delete relationship table

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a Spring Boot project using JpaRepository.

I have two entities, Threat and Dimension, in the database I have 3 tables:
tbl_threat, tbl_dimension and tbl_threat_dimension (that relates which dimension each threat has)

I want to delete a relationship row in thread_dimension table. How can I solve this?

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_threat")
```

public class Threat {

```
@Id
private String id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToOne
private User user;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "threat_dimension", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "threat_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "dimension_id")})
private List<Dimension> dimensions;


@Entity(name = "tbl_dimension")
```

public class Dimension {

```
@Id
private String id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
```

}

[image: tbl_threat_dimension]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing a mapping `Set<Thread>` in your dimension class, since this is a many-to-many relationship. With a proper `@mappedBy` annotation a deletion should also delete the corresponding relationship entry.

I would also suggest you should use `Set<Dimensions>` instead of a `List<Dimensions>`. Sooner or later you would have a lot of performance issues. See: [Hibernate Many to Many Relations Set Or List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174667/hibernate-many-to-many-relations-set-or-list)

Also keep in mind that `CascadeType.ALL` also includes `CascadeType.REMOVE` which causes to delete e.g. all Thread entries which has a relationship for a specific Dimension. See: [How to delete a row in join table with JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235303/how-to-delete-a-row-in-join-table-with-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

For specifying the table name you should use `@Table(name = "table_name")`. Keep the `@Entity` annotation, but setting `name` for `@Entity` is not used to specify the table name.

Check out this answer to see the difference between setting the `name` for `@Entity` & `@Table`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18732732/2464528